# How to execute error-failure command via SQL code?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, jobs

I need to execute Fail-Error command via code in SQL, in order to block job execution.

I have created a SQL Job, composed in two Steps, in some specifics cases I need to call tho failure-command(in Step 1) and stop executing job (and not execute the Step 2).

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a solution.

```
THROW 51000, 'ERROR', 1;
```

This line commang generate an execution error.